# Error while adding error bars to subplots in seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, python-3.5

I have the following example code which I want to plot as bar subplots using seaborn in one figure. I can plot the actual data as bar plots but when i try to add error bars, i get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'
```

code is:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['7.5'],
    'B': ['2.4']
})

df1_err = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['2.3'],
    'B': ['1.2']
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['5.5'],
    'B': ['4.2']
})

df2_err = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['1.7'],
    'B': ['2.1']
})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(6, 4), sharey=True)
my_pal = {"A": "green", "B":"orange"}
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
plt.tight_layout()


sns.barplot(data=df1, palette=my_pal, yerr = df1_err, linewidth=2,edgecolor=[".1","0.1"], ax=axes[0])
sns.barplot(data=df2, palette=my_pal, yerr = df2_err, linewidth=2,edgecolor=[".1","0.1"], ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

If I remove `yerr` from the `sns.barplot()` commands, it does create bar plots as I want, but I could not manage to add pre-calculated error bars to these subplots. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['7.5'],
    'B': ['2.4']
}).astype(float)

df1_err = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['2.3'],
    'B': ['1.2']
}).astype(float)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(6, 4), sharey=True)

axes[0].bar(df1.T.index.values, np.squeeze(df1.T.values), yerr=np.squeeze(df1_err.T.values))

plt.show()
```